# Embed characters in multiple dynamic textfields

Tags: flash, actionscript, text, actionscript-2, character

How can I embed some characters one time, and have them embedded in all my dynamic textfields?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can do that by default, but you can do something close:
1. You go to the library, select "new font".
2. You pick your font, for example "Myriad Pro", check the "export for Actionscript" checkbox. You get a message about a class not existing and being generated at runtime - you press "OK" and don't worry.
3. When you define your dynamic textfields, you do the following:

```
var textFormat:TextFormat = new TextFormat();
textFormat.font = 'Myriad Pro';
textBox.setTextFormat(textFormat);
textBox.defaultTextFormat = textFormat;
```

Of course, you only need to define the textFormat once, if no differences in size or other attributes exist. The `setTextFormat(textFormat)` applies for the text already in the textbox, whereas the `defaultTextFormat` applies for the text that's going to be added from that point on to the textbox.

That should do the trick. Tested in Flash CS4.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the Flash IDE, you can use [JSFL](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/main/wwhelp/wwhimpl/common/html/wwhelp.htm?context=LiveDocs_Parts&file=Part7_Extending_Flash_1.html) to automatically embed characters in textfields. [Here is an example.](http://blog.samueltoth.com/?p=142)